# Reroute water around garage

Tags: leak, garage, waterproofing

I am having some issues during spring / rainfall. Because one corner of my garage is low, all the water pools, which then comes into the garage. I find myself constantly trying to broom the water away.

My ideas:

1) For around the door, can I just dig down say a foot around the sidewalk along the side of the garage towards the back and fill it with gravel?

2) For the portion by the garage door, can I use a bit of concrete to create a bump, to allow the water to channel down toward the backlane? Perhaps a large rubber stopper?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your plans will work to keep water out for a while. I would trench to a lower area and use some rock it will act as a drain, the only problem will be after years of use it may plug with soil, grass clippings and other organics but if I'd dosent freeze it will work until then. A bump that is sealed will stop water but you don't want standing water there it will rot out the wood. Try the gravel first hopefully you have some grade away from the house and the gravel will make a nice drain.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for sanity check. Just don't want to do something dumb. Garage is generally a tear down in my opinion, just trying to keep it standing until I sell the house in the next couple years. Anything I should use in particular to seal the bump?